# MDX/SSAS sum of certain values over totals - calculate success/failure rate

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a simplified example cube used for learning purposes, and to try to figure out a more complex problem.

The cube represents a small web server log,

- number of hits as a measure
- hostname as a dimension
- http status code as a dimension

I can get a breakdown on number of hits per host and http status code with the MDX

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[CNT HITS] } ON COLUMNS, 
       NON EMPTY { ([DIM NOS STATUSCODE].[Statuscode].[Statuscode].ALLMEMBERS * 
                    [DIM NOS HOST].[HOST].[HOST].ALLMEMBERS ) }  ON ROWS 
FROM [DW]
```

[image]

Now what I would like is to make groups over various HTTP status codes to e.g. show the percentage of successful hits (all 2xx status codes), the percentage unsuccessful hits (all non 2xx status codes).

I can do this with SQL, but I'm at a loss on how to do it with MDX. e.g. with SQL I'd do:

```
select HOST,  
       sum(CNT_HITS) as HITS ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.statuscode div 100 = 2 THEN CNT_HITS ELSE 0 END)/sum(CNT_HITS) * 100 as success_percent,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.statuscode div 100 = 2 THEN 0 ELSE CNT_HITS END)/sum(CNT_HITS) * 100 as failed_percent,
       sum(CASE WHEN s.statuscode = 401 THEN CNT_HITS ELSE 0 END)/sum(CNT_HITS) * 100 as auth_fail_percent
       from FACT_NOS_HTTPLOG fact  
group by HOST;
```

And for the data shown in the above screenshot, I'd get

```
+-----------------+------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+
| HOST            | HITS | success_percent | failed_percent | auth_fail_percent |
+-----------------+------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+
| www.example.com | 1610 |         93.1677 |         6.8323 |            6.2112 |
| www.test.com    |   50 |          0.0000 |       100.0000 |            0.0000 |
+-----------------+------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+
```

But how can I accomplish this with MDX ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to accomplish this is to add a column to your fact table (or view/query) that would contain keys for either success_percent, failed_percent or auth_fail_percent. Then create a new dimension with these 3 members. Join to the fact and you have your solution without the need for any MDX at all.

Comment: Can you expand with some more details, I am not able to fully understand what I should do - though it sounds like a not so flexible solution .- what if tomorrow I want another group based on some other http status range ? Also - what do you mean without any mdx at all ? How else can I get the data from SSAS ?

Comment: @binary01 (upped) this solution will be the most efficient

Comment: @binary01if you still need more details let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra attribute [Status] to your [DIM NOS STATUSCODE] dimension and use MDX for percentage, like this:

```
([DIM NOS STATUSCODE].[Status].&[Failed],[Measures].[CNT HITS]) / [Measures].[CNT HITS]
```

Comment: Thanks - my attempt became [this](http://i.imgur.com/ahix432.png) , which seems to give the correct percentages. However if I also include the `[statuscode]` dimensions, the percentages just becomes nonsense, as shown [here](http://i.imgur.com/37gZrnT.png) - I'd expect that case to either show null/0 or 100% success rate for the respective status codes. , I'm worried there's more cases as well then which can produce bad results.

Comment: Replace ([DIM NOS STATUSCODE].[SUCCESS].&[SUCCESS],[Measures].[CNT HITS]) with [Measures].[CNT HITS SUCCESS] by adding the field as extra measure: CASE WHEN s.statuscode div 100 = 2 THEN CNT_HITS ELSE NULL END

Comment: Ok - that appears to work. But it seems very unflexible... Cube structure has to be changed and reprocessed if some new category of status codes are needed... whilst with a pure SQL solution, it's just a matter of altering the SQL..

Answer (score 0):

It will involve a certain amount of hard coding - although you could add these measures into your cube script.

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[failed_percent] AS
    DIVIDE(
       (
          [DIM NOS STATUSCODE].[Status].&[Failed]
         ,[DIM NOS HOST].[HOST].currentmember
         ,[Measures].[CNT HITS]
       )
      , (
          [DIM NOS STATUSCODE].[Status].[All]
         ,[DIM NOS HOST].[HOST].currentmember
         ,[Measures].[CNT HITS]
       )
    )
SELECT 
NON EMPTY 
   { 
     [Measures].[CNT HITS] 
    ,[Measures].[failed_percent]   
   } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
   [DIM NOS HOST].[HOST].[HOST].ALLMEMBERS
  ON ROWS 
FROM [DW];
```